# PHP nested 'foreach' loop only using last value of array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach, nested-loops

I wrote the following loop to create WordPress custom controls quicker:

```
<?php
  /* Creates "Color Scheme" section */
  $wp_customize->add_panel('color_scheme', array(
    'title' => 'Color Scheme',
    'priority' => 120,
  ));
    /* Creates "Navbar" section */
    $wp_customize->add_section('navbar', array(
      'title'    => 'Navbar',
      'description' => '',
      'priority' => 120,
      'panel' => 'color_scheme'
    ));
      /* Navbar Color Controls */
      $color_controls = array("menu-bg-color", "menu-button-color", "menu-site-title-color", "menu-overlay-bg-color", "menu-items-color");
      $color_labels = array("Background Color", "Button Color", "Title Color", "Overlay Background Color", "Overlay Item Color");
      foreach($color_controls as $control) {
        foreach($color_labels as $label) {
          $wp_customize->add_setting($control);
          $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, $control, array(
            'label' => $label,
            'section' => 'navbar',
            'settings' => $control
          )));
        }
      }
?>
```

This is the outcome: [Screenshot of my WordPress customizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsrOl.png)
Its not looping through the labels and its only using the last value.

Comment: Are you sure you want a nested loop here anyways?  Your controls and labels seem to be matched up 1:1.  You want a control "menu-bg-color" with a label "Background Color"... control "menu-button-color" with label "Button Color" and so on, right?

Comment: Yah, I want my controls and labels to match up. I think I want a nested loop, but if there is a better way to do it, I definatly want to learn how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$color_controls = array(
  "menu-bg-color" => "Background Color", 
  "menu-button-color" => "Button Color", 
  "menu-site-title-color" => "Title Color", 
  "menu-overlay-bg-color" => "Overlay Background Color", 
  "menu-items-color" => "Overlay Item Color"
);

foreach ($color_controls as $control => $label) {
  $wp_customize->add_setting($control);
  $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, $control, array(
    'label' => $label,
    'section' => 'navbar',
    'settings' => $control
  )));
}
```

I think this is what you're looking for.  A nested loop is for when you want one of each item in array2 for each item in array1.  You actually want an associative array of keys and values and to loop through them where keys are your controls that map to your values which are labels.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much for showing me what an associative array is! This is a game changer for me!